# tvOS: <grid> with lockup titles always visible (not just on highlight)

Tags: javascript, tvos, apple-tv, tvml

I'm using the catalogTemplate available for tvOS. In the relatedContent area (populated by a grid), I need the lockups to always show the video title. Currently, it only displays when the item is highlighted. Is there any way to fix this?

Here is my TVML. (The data from the backend is rendered by Mustache.js)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<document>
  <catalogTemplate theme="dark">
    <banner>
      <title style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); tv-align: left; font-size: 40; padding: 50; font-weight: bold;">Categories</title>
    </banner>
    <list>
      {{#data.categories}}
      <section>
        <listItemLockup>
          <title style="font-size: 30;">{{category}}</title>
          <relatedContent>
            <grid>
              <header>
                <title style="font-weight: bold;">{{category}}</title>
              </header>
              <section>
                {{#videos}}
                <lockup videoURL="{{video_url}}">
                    <img src="{{thumbnail_url}}" width="300" height="169" />
                    <title>{{title}}</title>
                </lockup>
                {{/videos}}
              </section>
            </grid>
          </relatedContent>
        </listItemLockup>
      </section>
      {{/data.categories}}
    </list>
  </catalogTemplate>
</document>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

While not ideal, I was able to accomplish this by using a  instead of  to display the video title.

Comment: It looks like you left out the critical component to this answer, the answer. Using a _____ instead of  _____ to display the video title. Can you fill in the blanks here?

Answer (score 1):

I think setting `tv-text-highlight-style` style will help you solve your problem:

```
<title style="tv-text-highlight-style: marquee-on-highlight">{{title}}</title>
```

Other options and styles can be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/ITMLStyles.html)

Answer (score 0):

I was having same issue as yours. I resolved it by replacing **videourl** with **onselect**. Here is example:

```
    <lockup onselect="playMedia('path to video', 'video')">
          <img src="path to image" width="182" height="274"/>
          <title>Movie 1</title>
    </lockup>
```

Found it [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/TVMLKitJS/Conceptual/TVMLProgrammingGuide/PlayingVideo.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016718-CH13-SW1)

playMedia() is function in .js file it's code is as below.

```
function playMedia(extension, mediaType) {
    var videourl = baseURL + extension;
    var singleVideo = new MediaItem(mediaType, videourl);
    var videoList = new Playlist();
    videoList.push(singleVideo);
    var myPlayer = new Player();
    myPlayer.playlist = videoList;
    myPlayer.play();
}
```